# New SharePoint site returns 505 upon creation

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

I have an instance of SharePoint WSS 3.0 running on Windows Server Standard VM; which I believed worked fine upon initial setup.  However, in an effort to get PerformancePoint and other Microsoft software (like SQL Server 2008) running on the same machine; I've been applying patches, service packs and installing and uninstalling frameworks.  Somewhere along the line, SharePoint seems to have broken.  I can create a new application and site collection, however when I try to navigate to the website, I get a 505 error.  It seems like all of the services are running and I'm logged in as an Admin.  I can't find anything in the server and event logs.  Any suggestions for debugging this problem would be helpful.  I may just end of reinstalling WSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new web application to see if it works correctly. You can also use Fiddler to find out if the request you are sending to the server is incorrect in some way.

But personally, I would go for a re-install, as it would definately take less time (2 hours? 3?). You said you've installed a bunch of fixes/updates, something could've just got screwed up along the way and untangling the mess could turn out to be just too time consuming